# Plotting the 3D region that determines a volume

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, regions

I need to plot this with *Mathematica*:

> Use a triple integral to determine the volume of the region below $z = 4 - x\,y$ and above the region in the xy-plane defined by $0 \leq x \leq2,\ 0 \leq y \leq 1$

I want to learn how to plot such regions in *Mathematica*; it would help me a lot in studying triple integrals.

Answer (score 11):

```
region = ImplicitRegion[
   0 < z < 4 - x*y && 0 <= x <= 2 && 0 <= y <= 1,
   {x, y, z}];

RegionPlot3D[region,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

```
Volume[region]

(*  7  *)

RegionMeasure[region]

(*  7  *)

Integrate[1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 4 - x*y}]

(*  7  *)

Integrate[1, Element[{x, y, z}, region]]

(*  7  *)
```

However, this can be done with just a double integral

```
Integrate[4 - x*y, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 1}]

(*  7  *)
```